# Trying to recover files from a lockscreen loop Pixel 4 with ADB pull

Tags: android, cmd, adb, google-pixel

I am trying to use ADB pull to recover my files from my Pixel 4 but I am getting
the error message "adb: error: failed to access '4' : No such file or directory".

[image]

What does this mean? USB debugging is on and my device shows up on adb devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the folder name to PIXEL4 and then try again.